# Android app stops working after 15 minute intervals

Tags: android, gps

I'm writing an app that takes GPS data and uploads it to web server.  It has an activity front end that launches a service which handles the all the heavy lifting.  My problem is that the app just stops working after some interval of 15 minutes (this could just be a coincidence) or occassional runs fine.  I put a partial wakelock on both the activity and the service.  The app doesn't appear to be crashing (I implemented the unhandled exception solution on this site).  Does anyone have any other ideas of something I should be looking into?  It's driving me crazy.  Thanks.

Comment: Can you be more explicit than "stops working"?

Comment: The data stops uploading to the webserver.  It's not a wireless coverage issue.  It never starts uploading again.  It is programmed so it can handle going into a bad cell area and I have seen that work properly.

Comment: Not sure what to tell you. Does the code execute? Where is the breakage happening. Details please, details.

Comment: The app runs fine.  If someone runs the app, their location is uploaded and you can go to a website and see the route they are taking real-time.  But sometimes after 15 or 30 or 45 minutes, the updates just stop coming.  Once they stop coming, they never start up again.  The app isn't creating any crash logs.  The best I could come up with was that the phone was going to sleep and stopped blasting the updates but I turned on the wakelock and it's still having this issue.

Answer (score 0):

> Does anyone have any other ideas of something I should be looking into?

If your app is not crashing, you should still log every process that is running and the expected results of all your methods. This will help you find where exactly your problem lies.

Examples:

1. Log the time the web service took to upload the data.
2. Log the response from the server.
3. Log a message right before uploading.
4. Use `try() catch` to determine if there is an error happening that you are not aware of and log those messages.

That's the best advice anyone can give you without seeing your code or knowing anything about your app.